# Sql query between statement placing temptable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created temp table named temp_table and have record as

```
       FromDate                ToDate
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000  |  2012-08-16 17:26:44.827
2012-08-16 17:29:06.980  |  2115-01-23 16:29:46.443
```

and I had place between statement as

```
select * 
from payment p 
inner join temp_table t 
    on t.FromDate >= p.CreatedDate 
    or t.toDate <= p.CreatedDate 
where createddate between temp_tbl.FromDate and temp_tbl.ToDate
```

But it is counting on 1 row statement, I want both statement to call.

Comment: on t.FromDate >= p.CreatedDate 
    or t.toDate <= p.CreatedDate 
 
is actually the same as
createddate between temp_tbl.FromDate and temp_tbl.ToDate

You can not have have the same createdate to be between both of your results

Comment: @sidux your statement is not correct. If p.CreateDate is '1990-01-01' both rows are returned. But I guess it is a mistake posted in the question.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk could you please explain? 
2012-08-16 17:26:44.827 <= '1990-01-01' -- false
2115-01-23 16:29:46.443 <= '1990-01-01' -- false
 '1990-01-01' between '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2012-08-16 17:26:44.827' --false
 '1990-01-01' between '2012-08-16 17:29:06.980' AND '2115-01-23 16:29:46.443' --false
or I misunderstood you
My point was that the same date can not be in 2 different intervals that do not intersect

Comment: @sidux I know this, but I am refering to the code in the question. I assume that the >= and <= has been reversed

Comment: @t-clausen.dk ohh... I see. Didn't pay attention to that. But how would it match BETWEEN condition? I mean '1990-01-01'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Between` operation to join the tables `On` condition. Try this.

```
select * 
from payment p 
inner join temp_table 
    on  p.CreatedDate between
        temp_tbl.FromDate and temp_tbl.ToDate
```

Comment: can I also write it as #temp_table temp_tbl ON ((P.CreatedDate between  temp_tbl.FromDate and temp_tbl.ToDate) or (P.UpdatedDate between temp_tbl.FromDate and temp_tbl.ToDate) or (P.checkdate between temp_tbl.FromDate and temp_tbl.ToDate))